# Что значит нижнее прямое серое подчеркивание в IntelliJ-IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

После обновления стали появляться серые подчеркивания. Что они означают? Их никак нельзя убрать. Как я понял, подчеркивается переменная в цикле `for`, которая используется только для функционирования цикла. Но почему тогда подчеркивается `numberOfPassengersInArrContainers`? А если подчеркиваются только переменные, которые потом не будут использоваться, то почему не подчеркиваются `а`, `passengers`,  и т.п.?

(подчеркивания помечены красными точками)

[image: Снимок IDEA]

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697168/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В [ответе](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000395439-Underlined-variables-) на официальном сайте пишут, что так подчеркиваются переопределяемые переменные.

---

Подчеркиваются изменяемые переменные и параметры.

IntelliJ IDEA теперь по умолчанию подчеркивает переназначаемые локальные переменные и переназначаемые параметры. Атрибуты для всех языков, поддерживающих эту функцию, которые на данный момент включают Java и Groovy, могут быть изменены в

**Preferences/Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Language Defaults | Identifiers | Reassigned** .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Чем это может быть полезно?**

Если переменная/параметр подчеркнута, вы знаете, что вы не можете использовать ее в лямбде/анонимном классе напрямую.

Answer (score 5):

Подчеркиваются названия переменных, которых нет в английском словаре. То есть, чтобы код был читабельным, проверяется орфография названий переменных. То есть, по умолчанию работает инспекция которая проверяет соответствие названий переменных со словами в словаре.

Более детально вы можете прочитать [здесь](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-code-editor.html#spellchecking).

Какие словари используются и как их устанавливать можно почитать [здесь](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spelling.html).

Comment: Ответ неверный, орфография подчёркивается другими линиями.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697168/intellij-idea-underlines-variables-when-using-in-java

Comment: @andreymal как мне показалось ОП написал что "подчеркивания помечены красным точками".